# How to make multiple plot with the same size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make 4 plots of data.frames in R, arrange them to 2 rows, 3 in the first row and 1 in the second row. I used the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotify)



# Loop to create 5 matrices and plot them
plot_list <- list()
grob_list <- list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  
  # Set seed for reproducibility
  set.seed(123 + i)
  
  # Create empty matrix
  mat <- matrix(nrow = 50, ncol = 4)
  
  # Set column names
  colnames(mat) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
  
  # Set row names to random strings
  rownames(mat) <- replicate(50, paste(sample(letters, 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = ''))
  
  # Set values in matrix
  mat[sample(length(mat), 3)] <- runif(3, 10, 100)  # 3 values > 10
  
  # Identify the locations of the missing values
  missing <- is.na(mat)
  
  # Generate random values between 0 and 1 to replace the missing values
  replace <- runif(sum(missing), min = 0, max = 1)
  
  # Replace the missing values in the matrix with the random values
  mat[missing] <- replace
  
  # Convert mat to a data frame
  mat_df <- as.data.frame(mat)
  mat_df$names <- rownames(mat)
  
  # Reshape the data so that it can be plotted with ggplot
  mat_long <- reshape2::melt(mat_df, id.vars = "names")
  
  # Create the dotplot with text labels and proportional dot size
  p <- ggplot(mat_long, aes(x = names, y = value, fill = variable, size = value)) +
    geom_point(shape = 21, show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "orange")) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 10)) +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(x = '', y = "Average expression level", fill = "Columns") +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 4, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
    guides(x.sec = "axis", y.sec = "axis") +
    theme(strip.placement = "outside",
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 14),
          panel.spacing = unit(0, "cm"),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
          axis.line = element_line(size = 1),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "black"),
          text = element_text(size=20)) +
    geom_text(data = subset(mat_long, value > 10), aes(label = names),
              nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 2, size = 3, check_overlap = TRUE)
  
  # Print plot
  print(p)
  
  # Add plot to plot list
  plot_list[[i]] <- p
  grob_list[[i]] <- as.grob(plot_list[[i]])
  
}

# Arrange plots into a 2x3 grid for the first row and a 2x1 grid for the second row
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(grobs=grob_list[1:3], ncol = 3),
  arrangeGrob(grobs=grob_list[4:5], ncol =1)
)
```

The result plot show that the 3 plots in the first row are the same size, but the plot in the second row are larger the those in the first row. Could you tell me how to make all the four plots the same size?

With many thanks

Comment: What library is `as.grob` coming from? `ggplotify`?

Comment: i in 1:5 will give you 5 plots not four. !

Comment: Yes, as.grob is from ggplotify. It should be 1:4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### option 1

The easiest way to arrange ggplots would be to use `ggpubr::ggarrange` i think ggpubr is one of the best ggplot2 additional packages especially for scientific publication stuff. I think `ggplotify` is the wrong call here, since it is used to transorm other plot objects into ggplot2- but you are just using ggplot objects anyways.

using ggpubr:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list,ncol = 3,nrow = 2)
```

### option 2

`gridExtra`package gives you full control over ggplot arrangements.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot_list[[1]],
                        plot_list[[2]],
                        plot_list[[3]],
                        plot_list[[4]],
                        ncol=3,
                        nrow=2)
```

To get the desired output (4 plots) i changed the for loop range from `1:5` to `1:4` (r uses 1 based indexing and includes the upper limit into the range.

Comment: Option one works fine. Could you tell me how to make plots in each row share one common y-axis title?